# MissingPluginException firebase_auth on invokeMethod from flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-platform-channel

Why there is a missing plugin firebase_auth (version: "0.15.5+3") when I call android native code? I always do packages upgrade. Everything seems ok and up to date. This error is not impacting my app but it is very ugly to see this error in the log output. firebase_auth is a Google product, so I expect it working perfectly without no errors.

[android studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fztr.png)

Flutter doctor:

```
/home/sony/soft/flutter/bin/flutter doctor --verbose

 [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Linux, locale fr_FR.UTF-8)
        • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at /home/sony/soft/flutter
        • Framework revision f139b11009 (il y a 5 jours), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
        • Engine revision af51afceb8
        • Dart version 2.7.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/sony/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /home/sony/soft/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /home/sony/soft/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.43.2)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.6.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • xxx • xxxxxxx • android-arm64 • Android 7.1.1 (API 25)

• No issues found! Process finished with exit code 0
```

Firebase versions:

```
  firebase:
    version: "7.2.1"
  firebase_auth:
    version: "0.15.5+3"
  firebase_auth_platform_interface:
    version: "1.1.7"
  firebase_core:
    version: "0.4.4+3"
```

The log output with an error

```
I/Timeline(14942): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@eac2d7f time:71001483
E/flutter (14942): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method currentUser on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)
E/flutter (14942): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:319:7)
E/flutter (14942): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14942): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:349:48)
E/flutter (14942): #2      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:43:10)
E/flutter (14942): #3      FirebaseAuth.currentUser (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:316:45)
E/flutter (14942): #4      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:45:6)
E/flutter (14942): #5      FirebaseAuth.currentUser (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:314:35)
E/flutter (14942): #6      Auth.getCurrentUser (package:digital_watering/services/authentication.dart:31:45)
E/flutter (14942): #7      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:45:6)
E/flutter (14942): #8      Auth.getCurrentUser (package:digital_watering/services/authentication.dart:30:38)
E/flutter (14942): #9      _RootPageState.initState (package:digital_watering/pages/root_page.dart:28:17)
E/flutter (14942): #10     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:58)
E/flutter (14942): #11     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
E/flutter (14942): #12     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
E/flutter (14942): #13     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
E/flutter (14942): #14     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
E/flutter (14942): #15     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
E/flutter (14942): #16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
E/flutter (14942): #17     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
E/flutter (14942): #18     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
E/flutter (14942): #19     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
E/flutter (14942): #20     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
E/flutter (14942): #21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
E/flutter (14942): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
E/flutter (14942): #23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
E/flutter (14942): #24     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
E/flutter (14942): #25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
E/flutter (14942): #26     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
E/flutter (14942): #27     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
E/flutter (14942): #28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
E/flutter (14942): #29     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
E/flutter (14942): #30     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
E/flutter (14942): #31     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
E/flutter (14942): #32     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
E/flutter (14942): #33     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
E/flutter (14942): #34     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
E/flutter (14942): #35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
E/flutter (14942): #36     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
E/flutter (14942): #37     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
E/flutter (14942): #38     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
E/flutter (14942): #39     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
E/flutter (14942): #40     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
E/flutter (14942): #41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
E/flutter (14942): #42     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
E/flutter (14942): #43     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
E/flutter (14942): #44     Componen
```

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to use stable channel. Also you get this exception when doing hot reload

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion ! 
I tried with a stable channel & without hot reload and the result is not changed